# Misplaced label in MUI Select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

could please somebody help me to figure out why Select label is misplaced in MUI5?

[image]

This is Textfield label:

[image]

This is Select label:

[image]

Code:

```
export const SelectItem = (
    {
        id,
        name,
        value,
        options,
        label,
        placeholder,
        variant
    }: ISelectItem
) => {
    const {setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();
    const [field, meta] = useField(name);

    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        const {value} = event.target;
        setFieldValue(name, value);
    };

    const configFormControl: IConfigFormControl = {};

    if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
        configFormControl.error = true;
        configFormControl.errorText = meta.error;
    }

    const helperText = configFormControl.errorText;

    return (
        <FormControl
            fullWidth={true}
            variant={variant as any}
            error={configFormControl.error}
        >
            {label
                ? <InputLabel id={`select-item-${name}-id`}>{label}</InputLabel>
                : null
            }
            <Select
                labelId={`select-item-${name}-id`}
                id={id}
                label={label}
                onChange={handleChange}
                {...field}
            >
                {
                    options.map((option: ISelectOption, index: number) =>
                        <MenuItem key={index} value={option.Value}>{option.Label}</MenuItem>
                    )
                }
            </Select>
            {helperText
                ? <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
                : null
            }
        </FormControl>
    );
};
```

Tried both ways, with Select itself (the code is above) and with <Textfield select ... /> - nothing changes, dropdown label is 3px below from where it should be.

Theme:

```js
import {createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles';

const DEFAULT_MODAL_HEADER_BG_COLOR = '#021e29';

export const getTheme = (colors) => {
    return createTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: colors.primary,
                contrastText: `${colors.buttonText}!important`
            },
            secondary: {
                main: colors.secondary,
                contrastText: `${colors.buttonText}!important`
            }
        },
        components: {
            MuiContainer: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        padding: '15px!important'
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiInputBase: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    input: {
                        backgroundColor: colors.inputBackgroundColor,
                        padding: '6px 7px 6px 7px!important',
                        fontSize: '15px!important',
                        height: '34px!important',
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans!important',
                        color: '#373636',
                        fontWeight: '600!important',
                        boxSizing: 'border-box'

                    },
                    root: {
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans!important',
                        backgroundColor: colors.inputBackgroundColor,
                        '&:before': {
                            borderWidth: '1px !important',
                            borderColor: '#626262 !important'
                        },
                        '&:after': {
                            borderWidth: '1px !important',
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiFormLabel: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        zIndex: 9999,
                        top: '6px!important',
                        left: '7px!important',
                        fontWeight: '400!important',
                        fontSize: '15px!important',
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans!important',
                        '&.Mui-focused': {
                            fontWeight: '600!important',
                            top: '0!important',
                            left: '0!important'
                        },
                        '&.MuiFormLabel-filled': {
                            fontWeight: '600!important',
                            top: '0!important',
                            left: '0!important'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiFormControl: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        '&:not(.mui-checkbox-root)': {
                            minHeight: '71px'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiButton: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        height: '45px',
                        marginTop: '15px',
                        boxShadow: 'none',
                        textTransform: 'uppercase!important',
                        backgroundColor: colors.primary,
                        color: colors.buttonText,
                        '&:hover': {
                            backgroundColor: colors.primary
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiFormHelperText: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        '&.Mui-error': {
                            margin: '0!important'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiCheckbox: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        padding: '0 9px!important'
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiTooltip: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    tooltip: {
                        backgroundColor: '#898888!important',
                        marginTop: '-17px!important',
                        maxWidth: 'unset!important',
                        textAlign: 'justify',
                        borderRadius: '3px!important',
                        borderColor: '#898888!important',
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans!important',
                        padding: '7px!important',
                        width: '370px!important',
                        '@media (max-width: 400px)': {
                            width: 'calc(100vw - 30px)!important'
                        }
                    },
                    arrow: {
                        color: '#898888',
                        '@media (max-width: 400px)': {
                            marginTop: '-0.65em!important'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiDialog: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    paper: {
                        maxWidth: '400px'
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiDialogTitle: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        backgroundColor: colors.modalHeaderBackgroundColor || DEFAULT_MODAL_HEADER_BG_COLOR,
                        color: colors.buttonText
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiDialogContent: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        textAlign: 'left'
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiLink: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        textDecorationColor: colors.primary,
                        color: colors.primary
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiInputAdornment: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        backgroundColor: colors.inputBackgroundColor
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiMenu: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    list: {
                        backgroundColor: colors.inputBackgroundColor,
                    }
                }
            },
            MuiMenuItem: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans!important',
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        fontStretch: 'normal',
                        fontStyle: 'normal',
                        lineHeight: '1.67',
                        letterSpacing: '-0.24px',
                        textAlign: 'left',
                        color: '#8e8b8b'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Comment: Can you try <InputLabel id={`select-item-${name}-id`}>{label ? label : ''}</InputLabel>

instead of how you added the label

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh nope, nothing changed :(

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed up your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-star-wbyxl1?file=/demo.js). The error was due to style overriding.

In your style, you overrode the MuiFormLabel top attribute to 6px which is pushing it downward.

I just changed its value to 3px, reducing the extra.

```
MuiFormLabel: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        top: "3px!important",
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: TextFields labels go up in that case

https://postimg.cc/3WQsf79x

Comment: I think there are some styles that are getting overridden. Can you please share a codesandbox including all the fields you want to use